# Import an SSL Certificate into IIS 7 from the command line

Tags: iis, ssl, command-line-interface

I have an SSL Certificate which has been exported into a PFX file.

How can I import this file into an IIS 7 instace from the command line?

I do not want to bind it against a specific site, just install it into the Server Certificates for IIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`certutil -p <PFXPassword> -importPFX <FileLocation.pfx>`

Example:

`certutil -p xyz -importPFX C:\cert.pfx`